# Persisting large collection

Tags: performance, hibernate, collections

I'm trying to persist a collection containing ~3000 objects as efficiently as possible.

Here's what I get in the logs:

```
Hibernate: insert into Animal (name, id) values (?, ?) \
...                                                     |
Hibernate: insert into Animal (name, id) values (?, ?)  |___ 3000 times
Hibernate: insert into Animal (name, id) values (?, ?)  |
Hibernate: insert into Animal (name, id) values (?, ?) /

Hibernate: update Animal set zooId=?, pos=? where id=? \
...                                                     |
Hibernate: update Animal set zooId=?, pos=? where id=?  |___ 3000 times
Hibernate: update Animal set zooId=?, pos=? where id=?  |
Hibernate: update Animal set zooId=?, pos=? where id=? /
```

I suspect this is because Hibernate does the following:

1. Persist the elements of the list (at this point the primary key of the list object is unknown)
2. Persist the list object
3. The primary key of the list object is now know. Update the ID of the owning list for all elements.

Is my understanding correct?

I would rather see that correct `zooId` and `pos` was used directly in the `insert`. Is this possible somehow?

(Using generator class `assigned` for the collection, and `sequence` for `Animal`. Tried `<bag>` as well. Same thing except `pos=?` doesn't show up, obviously.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mapping is missing but I guess, that your collection is missing the `inverse` attribute. For detailed information see: [1.2.5. Bi-directional associations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#tutorial-associations-bidirectional)

Some extract:

```
<bag name="animals" ...  inverse="true">
...
```

> The most important addition here is the inverse="true" attribute in
>   the set element of the Event's collection mapping.
>
> What this means is that Hibernate should take the other side, the
>   Person class, when it needs to find out information about the link
>   between the two. This will be a lot easier to understand once you see
>   how the bi-directional link between our two entities is created.

Other words, this setting will instruct Hibernate to

1) trust that Animal have a mapped property to holder/owner (zoo)
2) trust taht the ZooId is correctly set in our code (for each Animal in the collection)
3) allow to issue full INSERT statement... no UPDATE

So, assure that for each Animal was set the Zoo property before `Save` is called. The `inverse` will then do the job for us

Comment: Right. Sorry for not giving all details. Currently I don't use `inverse=true`. If I activate it, the `zooId` becomes `null` in the `Animal` rows. I guess that this is because an `Animal` has no reference to which Zoo it belongs. I'd rather not add such reference in the `Animal` entity, as it complicates the model and code. I understand how your solution would fix the problem, but is there any way to solve this without adding a Zoo-reference in the Animal class? (I mean, the Zoo-id should be available prior to insertion of the Animals, no?)

Comment: Well. The point is, that Hibernate manages Entities. It can do cascade for us, and store the `Animal`, while storing the Zoo. But the insert in this case, is about the `Animal`, The Update is about the managing relation from Parent to a child. From my experience, I would say, do not worry to change the model. It will in fact make your model more appropriate. You will gain *"only insert"* and even more! E.g. you can create criteria over `Animal` returning the ZooId, which could be used as INNER Select... very cool stuff. Only Zoos, having filtered Anmials... while paging will be still working

Comment: But having a `Zoo`-reference in `Animal` (and a `List<Animal>` in `Zoo`) creates nasty invariants (`animalX` must refer to `zooX` if and only if `zooX.animals` contains `animalX`). This invariant has to be maintained in the code, is error prone and clutters the business logic. I consider this to really be the last resort.

Comment: OK, I do not want to argue.. you know your business ;). I am just saying that this way it is designed. And working. And honestly, to me it seems to be natural. Because ORM means something more than pure model. We can still use some `protected` references, which could be mapped, and could be set only some way (constructor...) and then we gain the adavantage of `inverse`. Anyhow this is for sure the only way how to avoid insert and update. I respect that this does not suit to you...

Comment: I'm very grateful for the discussion. I did a benchmark (inserting 10000 animals using your approach) and it yields ~30% speed up. Thanks for your answer/comments.